# How to attach a windows forms application to a .exe process

Tags: vb.net, forms, attachment

once more I need your help.
Believe me, I've searched for this dozens of times, but couldn't find much useful information.

So the idea behind this project I'm doing, is to attach my vb.net windows forms application to a game called "counter strike global offensive", this is not a cheat!

My intentions are basically some helpful tools I can look at while playing, such as the time etc...

[Problem]
I've watched few videos, where this has been done, but oppositely, meaning they attached existing processes to their windows forms, ex. I saw a video where a guy attached the calc.exe to his windows forms application, and as you can understand, I want the opposite, I want to attach my windows forms to an existing application.

[Things I tried]
So what I did, was to copy his C# code, translate it to vb.net and mix it around, and I messed up badly :D

When I run my project it starts atleast 200 instances of each process (the game & the application) and I'd have to reboot my pc to shut them down :D

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Partial Public Class CubicCheat
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <DllImport("USER32.DLL")> _
    Private Shared Function SetParent(hwc As IntPtr, hwp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Sub CubicCheat_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        HookCsgo()
    End Sub

    Function HookCsgo()
        Dim csgo As Process = Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo.exe")
        Dim cubic As Process = Process.Start("C:\Users\redfa_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++ Projekter\Crazy Tutorials\CubicHook\CubicHook\bin\Debug\CubicHook.exe")
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        cubic.WaitForInputIdle()
        SetParent(cubic.MainWindowHandle, csgo.Handle)
        Dispose()
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What you are trying to do might not be possible since games like CS:GO either doesn't include the standard window message loop, or it ignores/handles certain messages differently. It is possible to render stuff onto the game screen via DirectX and hooks (beware of the _**Valve Anti-Cheat System**_! - also known as _**VAC**_) but that also means you'd have to do the hittesting and click recognition on your own.

Comment: Yea, I've heard a bit about the hooking and stuff, with ImGUI, DirectX and OpenGL and such, but aren't that some c# c++ stuff? And I can tell you for a fact I'm bad at those languages :D I barely understand vb.net :D:D

Comment: DirectX is mainly C++ but there are .NET wrappers such as SlimDX or SharpDX which both work in C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect your code to look more like this:

```
    Dim csgo As Process
    Dim csgoFileName As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo.exe"
    Dim csgoMatches As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(csgoFileName))
    If csgoMatches.Length = 0 Then
        csgo = Process.Start(csgoFileName)
        csgo.WaitForInputIdle()
    Else
        csgo = csgoMatches(0)
    End If

    Dim cubic As Process
    Dim cubicFileName As String = "C:\Users\redfa_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++ Projekter\Crazy Tutorials\CubicHook\CubicHook\bin\Debug\CubicHook.exe"
    Dim cubicMatches() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cubicFileName))
    If cubicMatches.Length = 0 Then
        cubic = Process.Start(cubicFileName)
        cubic.WaitForInputIdle()
    Else
        cubic = cubicMatches(0)
    End If

    SetParent(cubic.MainWindowHandle, csgo.MainWindowHandle)
```

Note that in the SetParent() call, we are using `MainWindowHandle` in **both** places.  You can't use Handle there, as it means something completely different.

Comment: Hey there Idle_Mind, thanks for your reply man, I appreciate the correction!

Comment: Hey there Idle_Mind, thanks for your reply man, I appreciate the correction! This didn't seem to solve the problem, but it definitely changed some things, and atleast it doesn't start up 200 instances now :D Although my main issue was to keep my vb.net form inside the game, the code you rephrased started up both processes but as singular processes, meaning I could move my windows form out of the game, which wasn't the purpose, would you have any knowledge or any kind of source I could look over and learn this?